# Ember data - Associated records were not loaded

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I try to load a mock Json, but im getting the following error:

*Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You looked up the 'author' relationship on a 'post' with id 2 but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify that the relationship is async (`DS.belongsTo({ async: true })`)*

here is the JSON from http://localhost:4200/api/posts/2

```
{  
   "post":{  
      "id":2,
      "title":"Monkeys",
      "date":"2013-12-21T00:04:20.461Z",
      "author":1,
      "body":"Vestibulum porttitor leo maximustae ultricies risus efficitur sit amet."
   },
   "author":{  
      "id":1,
      "name":"George",
      "posts":[  
         2
      ]
   }
}
```

**models/post.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('date'),
    author: DS.belongsTo('author')
});
```

**models/author.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    posts: DS.hasMany('post')
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't posts be side loaded with something like this `"posts": [ {"id": 1, "title": "one"}, {"id": 2, "title": "two"} ... ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try mocking your json like this?

```
{  
   "posts":[
       {  
          "id":2,
          "title":"Monkeys",
          "date":"2013-12-21T00:04:20.461Z",
          "author":1,
          "body":"Vestibulum porttitor leo maximustae ultricies risus efficitur sit amet."
       }
   ],
   "author":{  
      "id":1,
      "name":"George",
      "posts":[  
         2
      ]
   }
}
```

The error states `some of the associated records were not loaded`.

Comment: What if the records are already loaded on client side, like all the Authors data is already on client side, and then on Posts page you want "post.author" then?

Would it be a good idea to resend the exact same data again with Posts (Author details)?